# Xamarin PCL Android app suddenly crashes in release mode

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Xamarin (PCL) Android application suddenly randomly crashes when it released. It sometimes happens even when you are not currently using it and then message that app stopped working appears.

I wonder, is there any way to track whats going on, maybe there are some logs which I could have a look, or anything else to find out what the issue as I said it randomly happens and hard to find the problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to integrate Insights to get crash reports: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/insights/

Comment: Application Insights are deprecated now. Please try using  HockeyApp or consider MobileCenter. Visit: https://hockeyapp.net/  or https://www.visualstudio.com/app-center/

Answer (score 2):

A fast solution would be to plug your device and use the Android Device Monitor to see if it print out something on the device logs. 
 A more reliable solution would be of course to integrate a crash reporter system like what the others have suggested or Crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a crash reporting tool like HockeyApp or VS App Center, or wire up your own global exception handler